# ffmpeg-python Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [0]concat=n=1[s0] matches no streams

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to concat a list of audio inputs using ffmpeg-python.  The exception in the question title is being thrown when attempting to execute the following code:

```
music_streams = []
for path in random.choices(os.listdir(music_dir), k=song_count):
    path = os.path.join(music_dir, path)
    music = ffmpeg.input(path)
    music_streams.append(music)

music_joined = ffmpeg.concat(*music_streams)
out = ffmpeg.output(music_joined, 'out.mp3')
out.run()
```

Need advice on how to do this correctly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this on my own.  Adding v=0 and a=1 arguments to the concat call and it is working as expected.  If someone can explain what was going on here, I will +1 you for sure.  Fairly new to ffmpeg.  I am assuming the exception is because it is also trying to concat video streams (and their subtitles?), but since these are audio files, there are none.  ffmpeg-python needs to know this explicitly.  Could be wrong on my understanding, though.

```
music_joined = ffmpeg.concat(*music_streams, v=0, a=1)
```